# VueJS dynamic route hide when I hit enter on dynamic routes?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am working on a Laravel and Vue.js application. Here are two problems:

1. When I click on my dynamic routes it successfully works and goes to dynamic routes but in the same route when I hit on enter it can not load/show my dynamic routes.
2. When I click any dynamic routes its successfully show the component content but when I go to another dynamic route then route link was changed but the component can not change.

Here is my dynamic route component:

[image]

[image]

note: here only channels are dynamic
VueJS Routes
Dynamic NavBar

Laravel Route:

[image]

Dynamic Route content Component:

[image]

Comment: I've inlined your images, but pleaes [edit] this question and replace the images with _text_. Images are very hard to consume and work with.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a Single Page Application, then there will be only one Laravel route like this:

```
Route::any('{any}', static function () {
    return view('YOUR VIEW NAME HERE');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

Every incoming requests of any route will be directed towards one blade view and then you can handle your routing part with vue